# Holding reference to out of scope object's method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, garbage-collection

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, _label):
        self.label = _label
    def display(self):
        print(str(self.label))
    def get_display(self):
        return self.display

display_test = Foo(1).get_display()
display_test()
def inner_scope():
    global display_test
    display_test = Foo(2).get_display()
inner_scope()
display_test()
```

In Python 2.7, the above block prints 1 followed by 2, which isn't terribly surprising. What I'm curious about, though, is what happens to the objects generated by `Foo(1)` and `Foo(2)` -- it appears as though they have not been garbage collected as of the time `display_test` gets invoked, but does that mean `display_test` has a reference to `Foo(2)`, preventing it from being garbage collected at all? Am I just getting lucky that the objects aren't garbage collected before I invoke `display_test`? Does this differ in `3.x`?

Comment: It's called a closure. A closure is a combination of a function and the environment where it was created. The environment holds references to the values of the variables at the time it was created.

Comment: When you reassign `display_test`, the reference to the object created by `Foo(1)` is lost, so it can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, `display_test` holds a reference to an `instancemethod` object, one of whose attributes is `im_self`, the instance the method is bound to.

In Python 3, `display_test` holds a reference to a `method` object, one of whose attributes is `__self__` (the Python 3 equivalent of `im_self`).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Would upvote if I had the rep. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear.  This sentence: "it appears as though they have not been garbage collected as of the time display_test gets invoked" suggests some confusion.  In fact `display_test` gets invoked twice - one when it's bound to an instance method of Foo(1), and again when it's bound to instance method of Foo(2).  Until the call to `inner_scope`, display_test holds a reference to Foo(1) so it won't be GC'd.  After the call to `inner_scope` there is no longer any reference to Foo(1) so it is ready for GC.  But display_test now holds a reference to Foo(2) so *that* won't get GC'd.  So "they" - the objects Foo(1) and Foo(2) - don't get GC'd together but one at a time, each object's GC depending independently on whether there is any live reference to it.

Don't worry about the Python garbage collector.  It works beautifully.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how the last `display_test` gets `GC'd`. It seems `display_test` holds a reference to an instance of `Foo` - `Foo(2)`, and `Foo(2)`  holds a reference to display_test, so that seems like a circular reference. Based on my understanding Foo(1)` is probably `GC'd` *after* display_test is reassigned to `Foo(2).display_test` ?

Comment: @ffledgling I don't know why you would think that Foo(2) has a reference to display_test.  It doesn't.  The class Foo has only one member variable, `label`, the only thing in an instance of Foo that could possibly hold a reference, and in the example code it's just an integer.  And by the way, `display_test` itself is a global name and therefore the object to which it's bound will remain alive all the way to the end of the program.

Comment: To clarify: I was surprised that the first invocation of `display_test` worked, because `Foo(1)` wasn't referenced directly by any values in scope. It's method was held in `display_test`, but I didn't understand why that prevented `Foo(1)` itself from being garbage collected (making `display_test` safe to invoke).